# jQuery - treating a string as a variable name and returning its value

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a number of variables containing text strings and want to select which should be shown based on the element that is clicked.

The code below is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do, at the moment it sets the innerHTML of .msgBox to 'A_msg' or 'B_msg', what I want it to do is set it to the value of those variables.

```
    var A_msg = "You clicked A";
    var B_msg = "You clicked B";

    $(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
      var MsgToDisplay = $(this).attr('id')+"_msg";
      $('#msgBox').html(MsgToDisplay);
    });

    <div class="trigger" id="A">Option A</div>
    <div class="trigger" id="B">Option B</div>
    <div id="msgBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use an object:

```
var messages = {
    A: "You clicked A",
    B: "You clicked B"
};

$(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
  var MsgToDisplay = messages[$(this).attr('id')];
  $('#msgBox').html(MsgToDisplay);
});
```

You can write `messages[someString]` to get the value of property by name.