# Display a variable by referencing another variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I've set a variable and want call up that variable using the content of the link clicked.

I'm aware of how and why the button makes the content into "AddANewGallery" - but I'm trying to discover if it can show the content of the "AddANewGallery" variable instead.

The reason for doing this is so that I can set my content in variables which are then quickly referenced with the one small script rather than having multiple if statements or case - but if I'm way off on the best way to accomplish this I'd love to know.

http://jsfiddle.net/ta2T8/2/

```
var AddANewGallery = '<label>New</label><input type="text" />'; 

$('.whattodo').click(function(){ 
    variableName = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    $(".formitem").html(variableName); 
    $(".formsendbutton").prop('value', $(this).text()); 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following your intention. You say want the button to show "the content of the `AddANewGallery` variable". So you want the button to be changed into an input box?

If so, the following will accomplish this:

First, add `data-option` attr to your link tag:

```
<a href="#" class="gallerymanager whattodo" data-option='newGallery'>
    Add A New Gallery
</a>
```

Then, your javascript:

```
var whatToDoOptions = {
    newGallery: $('<label>New</label><input type="text" />'),
}

$('.whattodo').click(function(){ 
    var option = $(this).data('option');
    var $userInput = whatToDoOptions[option];
    $(".formitem").append($userInput); 
    $(".formsendbutton").prop('value', $(this).text()); 
    return false; 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/ta2T8/3/

Comment: Not quite the intention - when I thought about it I realise a better way to word the question and thus found someone who's had the exact same request and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Upon thinking of a better way to describe my problem I found someone else had an answer already

[jQuery - treating a string as a variable name and returning its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552679/jquery-treating-a-string-as-a-variable-name-and-returning-its-value)